# Use time intervals associated with groups to subset out data using dplyr and purrr functions

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm new to the purr package but would like to use it for the example outlined below instead of an apply function. I have a data frame which is in a long tidy format, that contains temperature data for multiple groups:

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
       Date.Time = c("5/29/2016 15:00", "7/20/2016 17:10", "6/2/2016 17:20",
                     "6/10/2016 17:30", "6/28/2016 17:40", "5/29/2016 17:50"),
           TempC = c(22.61, 22.235, 22.11, 22.36, 21.67, 21.54),
            Site = c("DH1", "DL1", "EH1", "EL2", "DH2", "DL2"))
```

This data set, at the moment, contains records that lie outside of target periods. I need to use the intervals I've generated below to pull out the records for each group that fall within any of the supplied intervals.

```
intervals <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
            Site = c("DL1", "DH1", "DH2", "DL2", "EL2", "EH1", "EH3", "EH2",
                     "DL3", "DH3"),
   full.interval = c("2016-05-29 17:00:00 UTC--2016-06-28 14:00:00 UTC",
                     "2016-05-29 17:00:00 UTC--2016-06-28 14:00:00 UTC",
                     "2016-05-30 17:00:00 UTC--2016-06-28 14:00:00 UTC",
                     "2016-05-30 17:00:00 UTC--2016-06-28 14:00:00 UTC",
                     "2016-05-31 17:00:00 UTC--2016-06-28 14:00:00 UTC",
                     "2016-05-31 17:00:00 UTC--2016-06-28 16:40:00 UTC",
                     "2016-06-01 17:00:00 UTC--2016-06-28 15:20:00 UTC",
                     "2016-06-01 17:00:00 UTC--2016-06-28 14:00:00 UTC", "2016-06-04 17:00:00 UTC--2016-06-28 14:00:00 UTC",
                     "2016-06-02 17:00:00 UTC--2016-06-28 14:00:00 UTC")
)
```

I know that I will need to use some combination of purr's map() and keep() functions and dplyr's group_by() but I'm not sure how to build the code to map across two data frames and for multiple groups.

The desired output would be a new data frame that contains records:

```
new.df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
Date.Time = c("6/2/2016 17:20","6/10/2016 17:30"),
               TempC = c(22.11, 22.36),
                Site = c("EH1", "EL2"))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify - Does the `Site` in `df` need to be the same as the `Site` in `intervals`? And as output you want the first or all cases where `df$Date.Time` is within the range of `full.interval`? How does the second output row become `EL2`?

Comment: @Jason, yes I essentially want to filter df by site and use the intervals data to keep all the records that match the site. I want to keep all records that are within that interval. And, sorry there was a typo in my example data. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Sure that makes sense- Should `DH2` be in the output? It looks like the time value in `df` is outside the range in `intervals`

Comment: @Jason, no sorry...it was late when I posted. Fixed it.

Comment: No worries, I posted an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't use purrr, but here's a way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# add discrete start/stop columns to intervals
intervals <-
  intervals %>%
  mutate(starts = gsub('--.*$', '', full.interval) %>% ymd_hms,
         stops =  gsub('^.*--', '', full.interval) %>% ymd_hms)

# associate each row in DF with the interval for that site, and filter
df %>%
  merge(intervals, by='Site') %>%
  mutate(in_range = 
           mdy_hm(Date.Time) >= starts &
           mdy_hm(Date.Time) <= stops) %>%
  filter(in_range == TRUE)
```

Update: this also runs fine when `df` is bigger:

```
# make a big version of df (3.7 million rows)
df_long <- df[rep(1:6, length.out=3.7e6),]

# associate each row in DF with the interval for that site, and filter
beg_time <- Sys.time()
results <- df_long %>%
  merge(intervals, by='Site') %>%
  mutate(in_range = 
           mdy_hm(Date.Time) >= starts &
           mdy_hm(Date.Time) <= stops) %>%
  filter(in_range == TRUE)
print(Sys.time() - beg_time)
```

On my macbook pro laptop w 16mb ram this runs in:

```
Time difference of 20.35184 secs
```

Comment: arvi1000, your approach works, but cannot handle large data sets. My full df is 350 MB and RStudio throws and error message while processing that it cannot handle a vector size this large.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't expect a problem with a moderately large dataset like that. What is `nrow(df)` and `nrow(intervals)`? Which line gives the error, and how much memory are you working with?

Comment: It’s 3.7 million rows. R spends about a minute trying to process then throws the error. The data df is only 135.8 MB.

Comment: I just ran the code again and it gave the same error but this time with a vector size 512 MB. Any idea why the vector size is increasing?

Comment: I think there's something else going on with your real dataset. The code above shouldn't struggle with 3.7M rows. Check the example code I added above and see if that runs for you with the dummy dataset

Comment: I've been reading in all my files at once, while simultaneously binding them. When I don't do this and only read in a single, smaller file the code runs.

Comment: So sounds like the question in this post is solved. Slowly growing a data.frame with rbind is infamously slow. better to do something like `rbindlist(lapply(my_vector_of_file_names, fread))` (using `data.table`), or `do.call(rbind..., )`

Comment: I'm using map_df().

Comment: In any case, this question as posted seems answered. Consider posting a new question that reproduces your new error. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments above, this is how I'd approach it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(Date.Time=as.POSIXct(Date.Time,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M",tz = "UTC"))
intervals <- intervals %>% 
  separate(full.interval, into=c('Start','End'),sep="--") %>%
  mutate(Start=as.POSIXct(Start,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz = "UTC"),
         End=as.POSIXct(End,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz = "UTC"))


output <- df %>% inner_join(intervals2,by="Site") %>% filter(Date.Time>Start & Date.Time<End)

> output
            Date.Time TempC Site               Start                 End
1 2016-06-02 17:20:00 22.11  EH1 2016-05-31 17:00:00 2016-06-28 16:40:00
2 2016-06-10 17:30:00 22.36  EL2 2016-05-31 17:00:00 2016-06-28 14:00:00
```